# iOS APP - Asset validation failed - An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024. What exactly does it mean?

Tags: ios

[image: Asset validation failed]

I get this error message when trying to upload my app to appstore. I've tried using visual studio, and I've tried using Transporter App. Both with the same result.

I wonder what this message means exactly? What file is it looking for - and what is it looking for in that file?

I'm sure I have added icon 1024x1024 in my Media.xcassets.

[image: proof]

I have this icon in a file called Media.xcassets, in the root of my xamarin.iOS project. I've also tried different places like Resoruces/Media.xcassets but with the same result.

No matter what I do I get the error "Asset Validation Failed, Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog".

The link to the guidelines leads to a page saying
**"The page you’re looking for can’t be found."**